# Cannot install flightgear on Ubuntu 15.04 because of broken packages

Tags: ppa, 15.04

I am unable to install flightgear using the information and data provided in [the PPA repository](https://launchpad.net/~saiarcot895/+archive/ubuntu/flightgear) indicated on the public site of the simulator.

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 flightgear : Depends: libopenscenegraph99 but it is not installable
              Depends: libopenthreads14 but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

The PPA contains hard-wired dependencies from `libopenscenegraph99` and `libopenthreads14`,

```
Package: flightgear
Architecture: amd64
Version: 3.4.0-0ubuntu1~ppa4~vivid1
Replaces: fgcom-data
Depends: freeglut3, libc6 (>= 2.15), libdbus-1-3 (>= 1.0.2), libflite1 (>= 1.4-release-9~), libgcc1 (>= 1:4.1.1), 
libgl1-mesa-glx | libgl1, libglu1-mesa | libglu1, 
libgsm1 (>= 1.0.13), libhtsengine1 (>= 1.07), libopenal1 (>= 1.14), 
libopenscenegraph99, libopenthreads14, 
libplib1 (>= 1.8.5-1), libpng12-0 (>= 1.2.13-4), libqt5core5a (>= 5.4.0), libqt5gui5 (>= 5.0.2) | libqt5gui5-gles (>= 5.0.2), libqt5widgets5 (>= 5.2.0), libsimgearcore3.4.0, libsimgearscene3.4.0, libspeex1 (>= 1.2~beta3-1), libspeexdsp1 (>= 1.2~beta3.2-1), 
libsqlite3-0 (>= 3.7.14), libstdc++6 (>= 4.9), libudev1 (>= 183), libx11-6, zlib1g (>= 1:1.1.4), 
flightgear-data-all (>= 3.4.0~), flightgear-data-all (<< 3.5.0~)
```

whereas those libraries have now reached respectively version 100 and 20.

```
apt-cache search libopenscenegrap
libopenscenegraph-dev - 3D scene graph, development files
libopenscenegraph100 - 3D scene graph, shared libs

apt-cache search  libopenthreads
libopenthreads-dev - Object-Oriented (OO) thread interface for C++, development files
libopenthreads20 - Object-Oriented (OO) thread interface for C++, shared libs
```

By looking on the web, I see that apparently the PPA is impossible to install since a few SO versions. Does this mean that nobody has installed flightgear in the last couple of years?

Comment: Hope that's the PPA you've vaguely refered to. Can you copy/paste the actual errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*I'm the Flightgear dev.*

Thanks for letting me know.

A rebuild of the package is happening, which should build it against the latest libraries in Vivid. The fixes package should be available in a hour or two.

Comment: Great to be of assistance. Fantastic quality control from your part. By the way, do you find upvoting my question too much of a hassle?